# Google drive remove permission from app after uninstalled

Tags: google-drive, permissions

I just installed an app that asked for permission to Google drive. I granted the access. Now I'm uninstalling the app from my phone, but I'm not sure if the app still has access to my Google drive. How do I remove the granted permission? or is it not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, simply removing the app doesn't remove the access to your account.

Go the "[Connected apps & sites](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pli=1#connectedapps)" section of [MyAccount.Google.com](https://myaccount.google.com), find the app (under "Manage Apps"), and revoke its permissions.