# How to I remove the authorisation of an app "connected to" Google Drive

Tags: gmail

Upon engaging apps to view files in Google Drive (e.g. "TIF, TIFF viewer"), I gave authorisation. How in general may I remove that authorisation? Drive shows the apps as "added" and "connected" to Drive, but the only option is to disconnect, and that does not indicate disauthorisation.

No answer at [Google drive remove permission from app after uninstalled](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105578/google-drive-remove-permission-from-app-after-uninstalled)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manage Third-Party Access

Disconnecting should effectively revoke access however
you can confirm what third-party apps have access to your Google account and also revoke that access at the following link: [Manage third-party access](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fsecurity)

#### Full Path

**[Google Account](https://myaccount.google.com/)  **>** 
                             
  [Security](https://myaccount.google.com/security)  **>** 
                                                   [Manage third-party access](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount.google.com%2Fsecurity)**